# I want to query the users with matching skills?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is my firebase database content of candidates_list.
cJrvsytFWDMG57NYIM1JLssv7wj1 this is the uid of the signed in user. Like these somany candidate list are there with unique uid.

Actually, I want to query the users with their skills. I want to show the candidate list with skills angular and React to the admin. Like this I want to list the candidates according to their skills. I have used angular tag-input to enter the skills in the form, I don't know how to query it according to their skills. Please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you look at the online manual for [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

Comment: Yes, you want to query the users with matching skills.

Comment: This is a categorization problem. If you want to show a list of users with a specific skill, you should store the list of users for each specific skill. See my explanation of why and how here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: the way i strectured the database is true or false?\